# How to change the CS Cart image storage location to outside work directory

Tags: cs-cart

We were having CS Cart project build as docker image and attaching external storage to the docker for file storage, but we can’t change the file storage directory outside the work directory.
Let say we have project at

```
var/www/html
```

then, we can only be allowed to save the files inside the same directory with the folder name as

```
/images
```

as per the CS Cart flow.
Not able to store the file

```
 external-mounted-path/images/*
```

[Simple diagram of what we have and what we need to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE0CB.png)

If you see the image we want achieve the below location configured for image storage

When we tried to change the path inside the configuration config.local.php file, it doesn't work.